# Existence of uniform approximator that also approximates derivative

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, approximation-theory

Let $S$ be a subset of $C^1([0, 1], \mathbb{R})$. It is a well-known fact that given a function $f\in C^1([0, 1], \mathbb{R})$ and a sequence $\{f_n\}\subset C^1([0,1], \mathbb{R})$ such that $f_n\to f$ uniformly, it does not necessarily hold that $f_n'\to f$ uniformly.

What condition on $S$ (or what condition on $f$) should we impose to guarantee the existence of $f_n$ such that both $f_n\to f$ and $f_n'\to f'$ in the uniform sense? Are there any non-trivial results to this question?

Comment: Firstly, I think there is a typo: you presumably mean that $f_n' \to f'$

Comment: Secondly: if $f_n'\to f'$ uniformly then it follows from the Fundamental theorem of calculus and **basic estimates** that $f_n \to f$ uniformly

Comment: The holomorpgic case works well. If a sequence of holomorphic maps  is locally uniformly  convergence then  its  derivative converges too. So the real case of this situation occures in power serises. Every convergence  real power series has convergence (higher order) derivative.

Comment: [deleted a comment which was based on a mis-reading]

Answer (score 1):

As you are asking for non-trivial results in this direction: There is a nice theorem of Nachbin generalizing Weierstraß's theorem
about dense subalgebras of $C(K)$ to dense subalgebras of
$C^\infty(M)$ for smooth manifolds (it has also versions for $C^n(M)$), some references are given in the wikipedia entry
[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem#Nachbin's_theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem#Nachbin%27s_theorem)